# mongodb aggregation referenced fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've 2 collections and one of this is referenced into second. Now I would like perform an aggregation query to grouping the second collection based on a field of first which are referenced into it

My model for first are:

```
first:{_id:ObjectId, name:String, region:String}
the second has this model `second:{_id:ObjectId, name:String, firsts:[$first]}
```

My documents look like this:

first document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("562a0f68f6a47a33b4000a52"), 
    "name" : "Name",
    "region" : "Sicilia" 
}
```

second document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("562a1250249c98273459be4a"), 
    "name" : "Name",
    "firsts" : [ 
        { "first" : ObjectId("562a0f68f6a47a33b4000a52")}, 
        { "first" : ObjectId("562a0f68f6a47a33b400084d")}
    ]
}
```

`

result I would like seam this

```
{
"_id": ObjectId of second document,
"region": "region"
}
```

I need to group second collection on every first.region. Is possible this?

Comment: We don't know if it's possible. perhaps you should show us  sample documents from your collections with the expected result.

Comment: I've just edited my question

Comment: And how should your query's output look like? Please make sure to well format your code this time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two option.

```
db.first.find({},{region:1}).forEach(function(doc) {
db.second.find({ "firsts" : doc.region });
```

});

or

```
var data = db.members.find({},{region:1}).toArray();
db.second.find({ "firsts" : { "$in" : data} });
```

Comment: I need to perform an aggregation query!